# AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'mark' for "from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score"

Tags: import, module, scikit-learn, attributes, pytest

When i try to import "sklearn" and use it, i am getting "Attribute Error",

```
## Modeling
# Multiple Linear REgression (Least Square fitting)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

The error from Jupyter notebook is as below,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9fc361c79a41> in <module>()
      2 # Multiple Linear REgression (Least Square fitting)
      3 
----> 4 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
      5 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
      6 #from sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split import train_test_split

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\__init__.py in <module>()
     17 from ._split import check_cv
     18 
---> 19 from ._validation import cross_val_score
     20 from ._validation import cross_val_predict
     21 from ._validation import cross_validate

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in <module>()
     29 from ..utils._joblib import logger
     30 from ..externals.six.moves import zip
---> 31 from ..metrics.scorer import check_scoring, _check_multimetric_scoring
     32 from ..exceptions import FitFailedWarning
     33 from ._split import check_cv

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 from .ranking import auc
      8 from .ranking import average_precision_score
      9 from .ranking import coverage_error

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py in <module>()
     34 from ..utils.sparsefuncs import count_nonzero
     35 from ..exceptions import UndefinedMetricWarning
---> 36 from ..preprocessing import label_binarize
     37 
     38 from .base import _average_binary_score

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
      7 
      8 from .data import Binarizer

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py in <module>()
      3 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
      4 from ..utils import check_array
----> 5 from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
      6 from ..externals.six import string_types
      7 

D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py in <module>()
    758     import pytest
    759 
--> 760     skip_if_32bit = pytest.mark.skipif(_IS_32BIT,
    761                                        reason='skipped on 32bit platforms')
    762     skip_travis = pytest.mark.skipif(os.environ.get('TRAVIS') == 'true',

AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'mark'
```

I have tried install/uninstall using pip
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn

(base) C:\Users\shashi>pip install scikit-learn

I am not able to uninstall sckit-learn package, it seems to be some path issue,

```
(base) C:\Users\shashi>pip uninstall scikit-learn
Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.20.0:
  Would remove:
    d:\anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.20.0-py3.5.egg-info
    d:\anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\sklearn
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'd:\\anaconda_details\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn' -> 'C:\\Users\\sh289528\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-w3d2aqtz\\anaconda_details\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 68, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 661, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 219, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 273, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\shutil.py", line 556, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "D:\Anaconda_details\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\anaconda_details\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\feature_extraction\\_hashing.cp35-win_amd64.pyd'
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am getting error again when i try to pip install.

```
(base) C:\Users\shashi>pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/fa/b50821115c16e9b8ca307d3788e3dd1ec71cade3e564953ed7330a1fa3e0/scikit_learn-0.20.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (4.8MB)
    100% |################################| 4.8MB 546kB/s

Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.3 in d:\anaconda_details\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in d:\anaconda_details\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.15.2)
twisted 18.7.0 requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed.

Installing collected packages: scikit-learn

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\\Anaconda_details\\Lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\feature_extraction\\_hashing.cp35-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried with conda uninstall and install. but that didn't help me either.

```
(base) C:\Users\shashi>conda update scikit-learn
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.5
  latest version: 4.6.9

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Comment: do you have a file called `pytest.py` somewhere?

Comment: ditto...........